# Is angular2 good for frequent DOM manipulation and major event handling

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2 but have experience in angular 1.x. So i have few questions.

1. Is angular2 good for frequent DOM manipulations??
2. How to handle event handling as angular2 doesn't support jqlite. jquery is not preferred to use.
3. Dynamic styling.

I want to have clear why how to handle these cases.

Comment: What is "frequent DOM manipulations"`

Comment: like finding element by Id . class etc. which was done by jqlite in angular 1.x adding css at run time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should be done by binding `ngFor`, `ngIf`, `ngSwitch`
   You can also add template variables and get a reference to them

```
<div #someChild></div>

@ViewChild('someChild') childRef;
```

2. `<button (click)="clickHandler($event)">click me</button>`
3. - `[class.some-class]="isSomeClass"`
   - `[ngClass]="someExpressionThatResolvesToClasses"`
   - `[style.backgroundColor]="backgroundColor"`
   - `* /deep/ my-component { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Did this answer your question?